# GULP executes watch-sass task only once after server start

Tags: css, sass, gulp

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watchSass = require("gulp-watch-sass"),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
    autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer")

function defaultTask(cb) {
    cb();
}

exports.default = defaultTask;

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    connect.server({}, function () {
        browserSync({
            proxy: 'localhost/'
        });
    });

    console.log('server started');

    gulp.watch(['**/*.php', '**/essentials/*.php', '**/essentials/*.phtml']).on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

    gulp.watch('./css/styles.css').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

    gulp.watch('./js/*.js').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    })

    gulp.watch('./styles/*.scss').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    })
});

var gulpRanInThisFolder = process.cwd();


console.log(gulpRanInThisFolder);

var config = {
    sassPath: './styles'
}


gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            errorLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
})


gulp.task("watch-sass", function () {
    gulp.watch("./styles/*.scss", gulp.series(['sass']));

    gulp.watch('./styles/*.scss').on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    })
});


gulp.task('run', gulp.parallel('serve', 'sass'));
```

This is my gulpfile.js. I have a styles.scss file which looks like this:

```
@import "flexgrid";
@import "main";
@import "navigation";
```

All import files start with and underscore and are partilas. I want them to be re-compiled and put into the ./css/styles.css
I get my browser reloaded each time I apply changes to any of my scss files, however, the changes are not applied.

As I am using source-mapping I can have a look the files in the inspector and I can see they do not get updated. Say, if I delete all contents for the _navigation.scss I will still have it's old contents after refresh with f5 or hard refresh with ctrl+f5.

What's wrong about my gulpfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your:

```
gulp.watch('./styles/*.scss').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
})
```

in the `serve` task, it reloads but never calls the `sass` task.  So you only call the `sass` task once (as part of the `run` task).  Change the above to:

```
gulp.watch('./styles/*.scss', gulp.series( `sass`, browserSync.reload ));
```

---

Or since you have a `watch-sass` task that is never called, make your `run` task look like this:

gulp.task('run', gulp.series('sass', 'serve', 'watch-sass'));

and you can get rid of the `scss` part in the `serve` task.  And simplify the `sass`watch` task to:

```
gulp.task("watch-sass", function () {
  gulp.watch("./styles/*.scss", gulp.series('sass', browserSync.reload);
});
```